# How to sum specified row and show in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a problem with show aggregate information in 1 row.

I have table like this:

[image: content of table]

And I want result like this:

```
1. dokId, sum(ilosc where paliwoid=1), sum(ilosc where paliwoid=2), sum(ilosc where paliwoid=3) for each dokid in each row
```

for example:

```
1, 2000, 6000, 0
22, 500, 0, 0
50, 300, 0, 200
```

I trying with join, subquery for query and i have darkness in my mind...
My first query:

```
select e1.dokid, e1.paliwoid, e1.ilosc as IloscON,e2.ilosc as IloscONA
from list e1
    left outer join list e2 on e1.id = e2.id
```

I probably must use something like this and aggregate this.

```
select dokid, sum(ilosc) as Ilosc, paliwoid
from list
where paliwoid = 1
group by dokid, paliwoid
```

Please some help.

Comment: Ofcourse, your right - MSSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  Dokid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paliwoid = 1 THEN ilosc END) pal1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paliwoid = 2 THEN ilosc END) pal2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN paliwoid = 3 THEN ilosc END) pal3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Dokid;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This is it what i want.